# How can I prevent from slash `/` from being forcefully added to my HTML link

Tags: javascript, html, web, url

I am trying to redirect users to a link outside my site and I want it to head to a particular section by using the pound sign `#` but html keeps adding `/` right infront of it

Code:

```
<a href="https://somesite.app#3D_AR" target="_blank">Walkthrough</a>
```

Keeps getting converted to https://somesite.app/#3D_AR.

I would like to be https://somesite.app#3D_AR

Comment: Those URLs are equivalent. All URLs have to have a path after the domain, and the root path is `/`.

Comment: @Barmar but there are some links that lead you to a section when you click them. Especially markdown

Comment: I'm not talking about the section after `#`. I mean that `http://somesite.app` is the same as `http://somesite.app/`.